# Is it possible to create login in Django with HTML forms?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am new to Django and I am creating a simple register and login functionality. I followed a youtube tutorial where the person used Django forms. I am trying to use just HTML forms for login and registration. The registration part is done and I see data on admin url.
For login I am getting None on this line:

```
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
```

Which is why I am not able to pass the if user is not None condition. Can anyone help? Here is the code:

This is the register part:

```
def createUser(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('username') and request.POST.get('password'):
        post = FormDetails()
        post.register_email = request.POST.get('username')
        post.register_pass = request.POST.get('password')
        post_save = post.save()
        print("data posted and saved")
        return redirect('login')
  messages.success(
    request, f'Your account has been created ! You are now able to log in')
  return render(request, 'users/register.html')
```

FormDetails is my model with email and password field(That's why i am seeing the password as plain text in admin page).

The login is:

```
def loginScreen(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print("username={}".format(username))
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        print("user={}".format(user))
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f' welcome {username} !!')
            print("here")
            return HTTPResponseRedirect('index')
        else:
            messages.info(request, f'account done not exit plz sign in')
    return render(request, 'users/login.html')
```

Is it possible with HTML forms? Any help or lead will be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

From the comments, I have made some changes. I have commented out the model file and now I am using form file:

```
from django import forms
```

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = User
fields = ["email", "password"]

and using it in register function in view:

```
def createUser(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    uform = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    # print("uform={}".format(uform.password))
    if uform.is_valid():
        user = uform.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        print("data posted and saved")
    else:
        print(uform.errors)
  else:
    uform = UserForm()
  return render(request, 'users/register.html')
```

But I am getting this error on clicking submit button:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Comment: Django normally *hashes* passwords, and `authenticate` will verify the *hashed* password.

Comment: But there is a long list of reasons why Django forms are preferred over processing the data with `request.POST` directly.

Comment: For example validating if required data is filled in, cleaning it to the corresponding type, running validators, running model validators, save many-to-many fields, editing an instance that already exists, etc. Using Django forms does *not* require to *render* the form, you can also simply use it to turn `request.GET`/`request.POST` data into an object.

Comment: thanks for the answer @WillemVanOnsem. I have made an edit to the question where I have implemented the django form but I wasn't very confident to apply it. I received the error I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank everyone for the answers that showed me the correct path. I was able to resolve the error.
After the EDIT 1 where I added the forms.py file and removing the models, I was able to get through the error of unique constraint on username by providing "username" field to `["username","email","password"]` field. The username was not provided by me earlier that is why a blank username was being created and next time I tried it showed username already exists as it was again blank.

Now everything is working fine. If anyone else is also facing the same problem I hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

Django uses set_password method when saving User password. You should never save password in plain text. That may lead to problems when trying to authenticate.

Comment: Hi thank for the answer. To use set_password, will I need to create a django form?